# python program to fill fixed-length-array with string without any whitespaces

Tags: python

I want to add a string, lets say "NEWYEAR", to an array with a length that is not necessarily the same as the length of "NEWYEAR" - whereas the array should be "fully" filled with the string, leaving no whitespaces behind. Roughly sketched, this is what I have in mind:

```
array = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] 
some_string="NEWYEAR" 

#add some_string to array until no place is left in array. 
#some_string should repeat itself until upper condition is fulfilled. 

array = ["N","E","W","Y","E","A","R","N","E"]
```

Could you tell me an intuitive way to accomplish my goal ?

Comment: You can just create a list with equal size to `array` and its contents are from NEWYEAR

Answer (score 1):

One could do

```
(list(some_string)*(int(len(array)/len(some_string))+1))[:len(array)]
```

or

```
[some_string[i%len(some_string)] for i in range(len(array))]
```

Comment: Would this be over-filled the original array then? PO asked for `fully` filled only, not clear `over-filled` is an option then. >>> array
['N', 'e', 'w', 'Y', 'e', 'a', 'r', 'N', 'e', 'w', 'Y', 'e', 'a', 'r']  # len is 14!

Comment: @DanielHao Yea. You are right. Don't know why. Removed first option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this but I think that one of the simplest is to use the `%` operator.

```
size_of = 15

word = 'NEWYEAR'

array = []

size_of_word= len(word)

size_of_word = len(word)
for letter in range(size_of):
    array.append(word[letter%size_of_word])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str_len = len(some_string)
arr_len = len(array)
for i in range(arr_len):
   array[i] = some_string[i%str_len]

print(array)
```

Comment: Often "just code" answers aren't useful, or at best they could be a lot more useful with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

### Code

```
len_ar = int(input("Enter Length : "))
arr_lst = [None]*len_ar
str_nam = input("Enter String : ")
f_str = (str_nam * (int(len_ar/len(str_nam))+1))[:len_ar]

for i in range(len_ar):
    arr_lst[i] = f_str[i]

print(arr_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way

```
import random

array = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
some_string = "NEWYEAR"

new_string = ''.join(random.choice(some_string) for i in range(len(array)))
array[:] = [char for char in new_string]

print(array)
```